# Which one is the stable version of angular?

Tags: angular

Currently, I am using 9.0.7 version of angular.
Can anyone suggest which version of angular is stable?

Comment: all major versions are stable....

Answer (score 1):

Here you can find the official supported versions of Angular:

> https://angular.io/guide/releases#support-policy-and-schedule

*All versions of Angular are stable as @Antoniossss mentioned, but new fixes and support will happen only in the 3 latest versions.*

*The Angular team, always make one major release every 6 months.*